# How change order of groups in nomenclature?

Tags: nomenclature, nomencl

This example will print the groups: Physics Constants, Number Sets, Other Symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{nomencl}
\makenomenclature

%% This will add the subgroups
%----------------------------------------------
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Physics Constants}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Number Sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
%----------------------------------------------

%% This will add the units
%----------------------------------------------
\newcommand{\nomunit}[1]{%
\renewcommand{\nomentryend}{\hspace*{\fill}#1}}
%----------------------------------------------

\title{Nomenclatures Example}
\author{ShareLaTeX Team}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

This is an example to show how the \textbf{Nomenclature} package works:

\clearpage
\mbox{}

\nomenclature[A, 02]{$c$}{Speed of light in a vacuum inertial system 
  \nomunit{$299,792,458\, m/s$}}
\nomenclature[A, 03]{$h$}{Plank Constant
  \nomunit{$6.62607 \times 10^{-34}\, Js$}}
\nomenclature[A, 01]{$g$}{Gravitational Constant 
  \nomunit{$6.67384 \times 10^{-11}\, N \cdot m^2/kg^2$}}
\nomenclature[B, 03]{$\mathbb{R}$}{Real Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 02]{$\mathbb{C}$}{Complex Numbers}
\nomenclature[B, 01]{$\mathbb{H}$}{Quaternions}
\nomenclature[C]{$V$}{Constant Volume}
\nomenclature[C]{$\rho$}{Friction Index}

\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

But how change the order to: Number Sets, Physics Constants,  Other Symbols?

Answer (score 2):

You only have to modify the redefinition of `\nomgroup` to become

```
\renewcommand\nomgroup[1]{%
  \item[\bfseries
  \ifstrequal{#1}{B}{Physics Constants}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{A}{Number Sets}{%
  \ifstrequal{#1}{C}{Other Symbols}{}}}%
]}
```